# Logging on Windows 6 Mobile application

Tags: asp.net, mobile, log4net, windows-mobile-6

I want to log events in a windows 6 mobile application.

Am basically looking for an equivalent for Log4Net but for a mobile app. In particular I want to be able to constrain the size of the log.

What recommendations to people have for logging on a mobile app or should I just roll my own.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use log4net? There is a .net cf version.